# How to match all requests (catch all) with Haskell Scotty?

Tags: rest, haskell, routes, scotty

I have a simple server

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty
import Data.Text
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

server :: ScottyM ()
server = do
  get "/" $ file "./index.html"
```

And i want to serve `index.html` on all the routes eg. `get "*" $ file "./index.html"`, but that doesn't work. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Same as in the provided example:
https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $
    get "/:word" $ do
        file "./index.html"
```

Comment: but ```get "/:word"``` will return 'file not found' when the second param is provieded with something like ```http://hostip.com/:word/:second_param```. And i need to get " * ". I know haskell and scotty in particular supports regex in its RoutePatterns, but don't know how regex, socotty regex works and how it translates form String to RoutePattern type

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want something like

```hs
  get (regex "^.*$") $ file "./index.html"
```

See [hackage doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.12.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:regex) for details.